# Messaging with 80000 producers and few consumers

Tags: architecture, rabbitmq, apache-kafka, activemq-classic, solution

We are looking to implement a monitoring system where we have to monitor some specifics from 80,000 nodes. We are also looking to generate reports from the 80,000 nodes. We are thinking of using a client on each node to send out messages to a queue where another program can read the messages and generate cumulative reports.

We are considering Kafka/ActiveMQ/RabbitMQ as some of the products for messaging solution. Which one is a better fit?

The message production rate will be approx 5-10/s per node.

Answer (score 0):

Try each one of those. Simulate your environment with 80,000 nodes and a processor( reader program) using each one of those technologies. Analyse the results and then choose one that fits your situation well. Feels like an IoT scenario, so try one of the IoT tech as well, such as Azure Event Hub.